# How to keep original image name in Laravel image file upload

Tags: laravel, image, file, file-upload

I am trying to upload or update an image file.but this code is changing the name of original image into a hexa number.How can i keep the file name same in DB and my project images folder?

```
      $image = $request->file('cus_image');

        if(($image)){
            $data=array();

      $image_name=hexdec(uniqid());
      $ext=strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
      $image_full_name=$image_name.'.'.$ext;
      $upload_path='images/';
      $image_url=$upload_path.$image_full_name;
      $success=$image->move($upload_path,$image_full_name);
      $data['pic']=$image_full_name;

      DB::table('customer')
      ->where('Cus_id',$Cus_id)  
      ->update($data);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$image_name=hexdec(uniqid());` to `$image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();`